# WHY !! CountDown not Working inside the IF Condition?

Tags: unity, c#

i need a way to make the countdown decreasing inside the if statement i am stacking in  this problem for more than 3 days .. Don't suggest to me Coroutine cause it will not working in my case cause i am using clones (initiated prefabs)

i know that the countdown will work only one frame if it's inside an IF Statement ... Any Ideas to make it working ...Ty

The game is about cars ... and every instantiated car has a random countdown timer

```
void Update()
{
    if(carNumber < cars)
    {
        SpawnCars();
    }
}
```

and this is the spawn  function

```
void SpawnCars()
{
    randomSpawnPoint = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);

    randomSpawnCars = Random.Range(0, Cars.Length);

    GameObject obj = Instantiate(Cars[randomSpawnCars],spawnPoints[randomSpawnPoint].position, Quaternion.Euler(-90, 180, 0)) as GameObject;

    carNumber++;            

    obj.gameObject.tag = "select";// + k;

    rcf = obj.GetComponent<RayCastForward>();
    TextMesh txt = FindObjectOfType<TextMesh>();

    time = Random.Range(4, 20);


    txt.text = (time - Time.deltaTime).ToString("0");
    print(time);
    print(carNumber);
}
```

EDIT: `time` is the timer

Comment: Is the `time` variable the countdown? If so you keep resetting it every time you run the `SpawnCars()`. I assume the intention was to assign the countdown to the cars?

Comment: `time`is  the timer ... even if i reseting it each time i  run `SpawnCars()` ... i tried run it  only onces but the timer didn't worked

Comment: If `time` isn't your countdown then where in your code is your countdown?

Comment: time is the countdown timer

Comment: Well first off. You're only calling `SpawnCars()` while carNumber is smaller than cars. Second off. You're resetting `time` every time you run `SpawnCars()` with `time = Random.Range(4, 20)`. Basically imagine you're moving boxes from one place to another but someone else keeps putting the boxes back. That's what your code is doing and that's why it never counts properly. If you want a countdown on every car you will need to assign them a script with a public time variable and then in the car script you decrease it in `Update()`

Comment: no wait ... First Thank you for trying to help me to solve it ... second i tried to call it only once but `time` never counted_down ... with this `if(carNumber < cars)` i can control how many times will run ...  `int carNumber  = 0;` always

Comment: You've already asked this exact question...

Comment: Well if you only call it once it will only count once. Imagine you need to count to 10 in real life but ONLY when someone says "GO". They only say "GO" once so you only count to 1. That's what happens when you only call it once. And again as I mentioned. Your code keeps resetting your counter. You need to re-read my comment.

Comment: yes i  tied a lot but  no solution worked for me ... that is why i re-posted it in easier way than the fist one

Comment: that's exactly the problem as the "GO" example ... how can i make this "Go" work for  every frame!? and about the resitting ... i tried too make up to 11 clone and they all had a different numbers ... So its not resitting

Comment: The `time = Random.Random(4, 10)` is what's giving them different number because it's setting a random number every time and every time you call your script it will reset to a new random number. I will rewrite what I already wrote. Give the car objects a script with a public time variable. Decrease the time variable in `Update()` in the car script.

Comment: ok ... i deleted `time = Random.Random(4, 10)` and i give `time = 20;` in `start()` ... nothing changed ... its always 20

Comment: That is not at all what I suggested. Your knowledge of C# and Unity programming is too limited and I would recommend learning some more basics before moving into game development.

Comment: wait ... i now exactly what is the problem and why  ... and my knowledge in  C# is good ... maybe not in unity ... that's why am lookking for  the answer here cause this problem isn't about c# basics its about logic (unity)... Ty  for you help anyway

Comment: I don't get exactly your problem : a) your "cars" variable is not at the right value and you spawn only one car? b) your "carNumbers" variable is not at the right value and you spawn only one car? c) if there is a null value and then an Exception your function will not be called again if not that we need more code or explanation about your problem to understand

Comment: Please do not re-post questions. Instead, if you feel your previous question was not clear enough, use the edit link to improve it. Make sure your edit shows us these methods in the context of the class(es) containing them, and show us where you're trying to decrease the timer after you've successfully spawned a car (ie. not inside the spawn function itself)